# Load a dictionary in python from text file

Tags: python, list, dictionary, text, deserialization

I have a text file config.txt with data formatted like this. Each key value is in a new line.
Value is a list of strings.

```
key_inv_single = ['invoice'] 
key_inv_number = ['invoice number', 'invoice no', 'invoice #', 'invoice#'] 
key_inv_date = ['invoice date', 'invoice dt', 'issue date', 'date of invoice', 'date of issue', 'issue dt', 'dt of issue']
```

I would like to deserialize this into a python dictionary with the same name as the file.

```
{
key_inv_single : ['invoice'] 
key_inv_number : ['invoice number', 'invoice no', 'invoice #', 'invoice#'] 
key_inv_date : ['invoice date', 'invoice dt', 'issue date', 'date of invoice', 'date of issue', 'issue dt', 'dt of issue'] 
}
```

Comment: Hi! Please add your attempt with your post,
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the following a try.

```
from ast import literal_eval
file = open("example.txt")
output = {}
for line in file:
    your_line = line.strip().split('=')
    key = your_line[0]
    lst = literal_eval(your_line[1].strip())
    output[key] = lst
```

output

```
{
'key_inv_single ': ['invoice'], 
'key_inv_number ': ['invoice number', 'invoice no', 'invoice #', 'invoice#'], 
'key_inv_date ': ['invoice date', 'invoice dt', 'issue date', 'date of invoice', 'date of issue', 'issue dt', 'dt of issue']
}
```

First we read the file and assign the key to a variable called `key`. Then we use `literal_eval` to turn the value into an actual list type. Then we add these values to a dictionary.

And ofcourse this can be done using dict comprehension but it ain't pretty.

```
from ast import literal_eval
file = open("example.txt")
output = {line.strip().split('=')[0]:literal_eval(line.strip().split('=')[1].strip())for line in file}
```